# Expresso-store selling events - entries or modifiers?

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, ee

This is a two part question as it relates to the same product type.

We're thinking of using expresso-store for this, but open to other suggestions (CartThrob)?

**1a) Store Product 1 - Events**

One of our products may be an ‘event’. An event might have several possible dates, for this example, lets assume there are three.

The user would select the date they wish to go to said event. Each date would have a limited number of items or stock.

**Question 1a:** Can each event be a single entry with modifiers OR would each date need to be a separate entry?

**1b) Store Product 1 - Events**

Lets assume a Manager needs to buy several tickets for an event for each of their staff.

**Question 1b:** At the point of adding multiple items to their basket, can a user add staff details against each of the purchased items? Ideally we’d need to add email address and First-name, Last-name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using modifiers on a product is indeed the best way to sell a single event with multiple dates, as each modifier can also have its own inventory.

As for adding something like staff details for ticket purchases, just add one or more "text" modifiers - this allows the purchaser to input free text for each item they add to the cart.